# What is the max size for a Redshift insert query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-redshift

I am trying to batch multiple rows of data into a Redshift `INSERT` query.  In order to keep it efficient, I want to know the largest length I can go before I need to start a new batch.  If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

EDIT:I was a little vague.  I am trying to got from Elasticsearch to Redshift.  This results in a JSON format that I convert into: `INSERT INTO xxxx VALUES (a1, a2, a3), (b1, b2, b3), (c1, c2, c3)`

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use COPY? It's far faster. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html

Comment: Batching wont help. you need to write to S3 then COPY.

Comment: @JonScott could you elaborate on why not?

Comment: Thanks for the edit - I now see what you mean by batching - yes that could help a bit. In my experience you will be taking maybe 0.5 seconds per insert. How many rows do you have to insert and how quickly do you want them inserted? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-use-copy.html

Comment: There are 100's of thousands of rows.  This is something we plan to run daily and in the background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximum length for a Redshift statement is 16MB.
Please see
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-sql.html

Much faster to move the data to S3 first then use the Redshift COPY command if you need to load a lot of data regularly.

Comment: Just discovered another limit ... you can only insert up to 32,768 (short/2byte) parameters into a SQL statement. Something you can definitely hit before 16MB, if you have small columns.

With respect to all the COPY answers... sure, we know, it's recommended. Automating, that, though, can also easily turn into a maintenance nightmare of shell scripts, code, threads, cron...

Comment: Btw, timed different batch sizes - bigger is definitely not always better. For my data, 4k rows per insert was about 18/sec, 2k, 30/sec, 1k, 70/sec

Answer (score 3):

The *best* way to load data is by using the `COPY` statement to load from Amazon S3. This allows all nodes to participate in the load in parallel and is the most efficient method.

If you have an application that is generating small batches of data that don't warrant a `COPY`, then it is recommended that you **[Use a Multi-Row Insert](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-multi-row-inserts.html) whenever possible**.

There is no specific advice on how many rows should be inserted, but the more the better (since it results in fewer batches).

If the data is already in another Amazon Redshift table, you can [Use a Bulk Insert](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-bulk-inserts.html) to **select from one table and insert into another table**.

See: [Amazon Redshift Best Practices for Loading Data - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_loading-data-best-practices.html)